# How to attach 3 Availability Zones within 1 AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-ami

I am working towards an automated Auto Scaling Group load balancing configuration for my Instances to automatically launch.

My User Data to launch an Apache webserver is:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
systemctl enable httpd
systemctl start httpd
```

**Problem:** It would only load the webpage and allow me to SSH onto that Instance normally if it was under AZ `eu-west-1a` and no other availability zones. I think this is to do with when I created the AMI of the Instance it was under `eu-west-1a` but I have a VPC with 3 subnets that should distribute traffic evenly between them.

How would I go about attaching all 3 Availability Zones instead of just one?

Comment: It sounds like you are launching into subnets in each Availability Zone, but only one subnet is working for you. This might be because the 'failing' subnets are **not Public Subnets**. Please confirm whether all of the subnets are public subnets (defined as having a Route Table entry pointing to an Internet Gateway).

Comment: "eu-west-1a and no other availability zones" - what do you mean by that? Is it about cloudformation template?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Oh wow yeah you are right, big facepalm moment. I created the first public subnet and then must've created the others as private without knowing.. So with the private ones would I just edit the route table to point towards the Internet Gateway or is there an easier way?

Comment: To convert a private subnet into a public subnet, add a Route Table entry pointing to the Internet Gateway. You could even simply edit them to use the _same_ Route Table as the existing public subnet.